# Why does the data from Firebase is loading just after refresh? (Angular)

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a website with angular.
The site contains a login page, and after the user logs in, there is a routing to the user's profile page, where data stored in Firebase should appear.

**For some reason the data appears on the screen just after refreshing the page.

Do you have any idea what the reason is, and how I can fix the problem?**
Thank you in advance!

Here is the relevant code in my opinion:

***profile.component.html:***

```
<h3 *ngFor="let item of user">Welcome back {{item.name}},</h3>
<h4>Your Details:</h4>
<table>
    <tbody *ngFor="let item of user">
        <div>
            <tr>
                <th>Name:</th>    
                <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Email:</th>   
                <td>{{item.email}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Phone Number:</th>   
                <td>{{item.phone}}</td>
            </tr>
        </div>
    </tbody> 
</table>
```

***profile.component.ts:***

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {CrudService} from '../services/crud.service';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  user: any;
  message = '';
  errorMessage = ''; 
  error: {name:string, message:string} = {name:'' , message:''}; //firebase error handle

  constructor(public authservice: AuthService, private router: Router,public crudservice:CrudService) { }

  ngOnInit(){
    if(this.authservice.currentUser != null)//We will make sure the user is logged in
    {
      this.crudservice.get_userInfo().subscribe(data => {
        this.user = data.map(c => {
          return {
            id: c.payload.doc.id,
            name: c.payload.doc.data()['name'],
            email: c.payload.doc.data()['email'],
            phone: c.payload.doc.data()['phone'],
          };
        })
        console.log(this.user);
      });  
    }
  }
}
```

***auth.service.ts:***

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth} from '@angular/fire/auth';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  authState: any =null;
  constructor(private afu: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) {
    this.afu.authState.subscribe((auth =>{
      this.authState = auth;
    }))
  }
  //get fanctions, to get data from firebase
  get isUserAnonymousLoggedIn(): boolean{
    return (this.authState !== null) ? this.authState.isAnonymous : false
  } 
  get currentUserId(): string{
    return (this.authState !== null) ? this.authState.uid : ''
  } 
  get currentUserName(): string{
    return this.authState['email']
  } 
  get currentUser(): any{
    return (this.authState !== null) ? this.authState : null;
  } 
  get isUserEmailLoggedIn(): boolean{
    if((this.authState !== null) && (!this.isUserAnonymousLoggedIn)){
      return true
    } else{
      return false
    }
  } 
  //function in use in login.component.ts
  loginWithEmail(email: string, password: string){
    return this.afu.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((user) => {
      this.authState = user
    }).catch(error=>{
        console.log(error)
        throw error
      })
  }
}
```

***crud.service.ts:***

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import {AngularFirestore} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CrudService {

  constructor(private authservice: AuthService, public fireservices:AngularFirestore) { }
  
  get_userInfo()
  {
    return this.fireservices.collection('users').doc(this.authservice.currentUserId).collection('user-info').snapshotChanges();
  }
}
```

***login.component.ts:***

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  email="";
  password="";
  errorMessage = ''; //validation error handle
  error: {name:string, message:string} = {name:'' , message:''}; //firebase error handle

  constructor(private authservice: AuthService, private router: Router) { }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  login()
  {
    this.clearErrorMessage();
    if(this.validateForm(this.email, this.password))
    {
      this.authservice.loginWithEmail(this.email, this.password)
      .then(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['/profile'])
      }).catch(_error =>{
        this.error = _error
        this.router.navigate(['/login'])
      })
    }  
  }

  clearErrorMessage()
  {
    this.errorMessage = '';
    this.error = {name: '', message:''};
  }

  validateForm(email, password)
  {
  .
  .
  .
  .
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That because subscribe in first return null or undefined. 
To resolve this issue your code will be like :

```
  this.crudservice.get_userInfo().subscribe(data => {
         if(data != null && data != undefined) {
            this.user = data.map(c => {
              return {
                id: c.payload.doc.id,
                name: c.payload.doc.data()['name'],
                email: c.payload.doc.data()['email'],
                phone: c.payload.doc.data()['phone'],
              };
            })
            console.log(this.user); 
       }
     }
```

You can also add ngIf in your HTML page

```
<div *ngIf="user != null" >
<h3 *ngFor="let item of user">Welcome back {{item.name}},</h3>
<h4>Your Details:</h4>
<table>
    <tbody *ngFor="let item of user">
        <div>
            <tr>
                <th>Name:</th>    
                <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Email:</th>   
                <td>{{item.email}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Phone Number:</th>   
                <td>{{item.phone}}</td>
            </tr>
        </div>
    </tbody> 
</table>
</div>
```

More detail is here :

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subscription 
Hope useful

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I changed the code according to your recommendation, but I still need to  refresh the page before the information loading. Could it be related to how I navigate the login page to the profile page? (I added the login.component.ts code to the question)

Comment: Do you have a hypothesis where could the problem be? @A.khalifa

Comment: I think this this.authservice.currentUser

Comment: Try to delete this code     if(this.authservice.currentUser != null)//We will make sure the user is logged in

Comment: Thanks @A.khalifa , I deleted this line, but the problem still remains

Comment: By the way, the only thing that appears on the page before I refresh, is the line of code: `<h4>Your Details:</h4>` @A.khalifa